# Serialize array without root node in restkit

Tags: arrays, serialization, restkit

I would like to post the following information to the server with restkit:

```
[
 { "title": "cvxcv" },
 { "title": "sdfsdf" },
 { "title": "qsfqsdqsd" }
]
```

I have defined the two following classes:

```
@interface ObjectTemplate : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;    
@end

@interface ObjectListTemplate : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *objects;
@end
```

Here are their mappings:

```
    // Object template
    RKObjectMapping *objectTemplateMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ObjectTemplate class]];
    [objectTemplateMapping mapAttributes:@"title", nil];
    [_objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[objectTemplateMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[ObjectTemplate class]];

    // Object list template
    RKObjectMapping *objectListTemplateMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ObjectListTemplate class]];
    [objectListTemplateMapping mapKeyPath:@"objects" toRelationship:@"objects" withMapping:objectTemplateMapping];
    RKObjectMapping *inverseObjectListTemplateMapping = [objectListTemplateMapping inverseMapping];
    [_objectManager.mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:inverseObjectListTemplateMapping forClass:[ObjectListTemplate class]];
```

The problem is that I am getting a root node whenever posting or putting an objectListTemplate to the server:

HTTP Body: {"objects":[{"title":"TestTitle"}]}

The server does not recognize this. I need to be able to get the following format:

HTTP Body: "objects":[{"title":"TestTitle"}]

Please help, this has been driving me insane for the past two days.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leave out the `ObjectListTemplate`, post an NSArray and define the inner mapping only. RESTkit should realise it's an array and will map its object to the defined mapping, which should end up how you want it.